# Error running ansible-playbook using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am getting the below error when I run an ansible playbook using Jenkins.

`Java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ans"): error=2, No such file or directory` "

This is what I have in my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
     agent any
     environment {
        PATH = "/usr/bin/ansible:/usr/bin/ansible-playbook:$PATH"
        ANS_HOME = tool('ansible')
     }
     stages {
         stage('Example') {
             steps {
                 echo "PATH is: $ANS_HOME"
                 sh "whoami"
                 sh "echo $PATH"
                 sh "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /path /to/myinventory.ini /path/to/playbooks/myplaybook.yml --extra-vars '{\"mode\" : \"running\"}'"
             }
         }
     }
}
```

It is being run as a root user as my output from sh "whoami" is root .Also path has /usr/bin , /usr/bin/ansible and /usr/bin/ansible-playbook

--------output below ---------------------------------------

```
> [Pipeline] {
>     [Pipeline] stage
>     [Pipeline] { (Example)
>     [Pipeline] echo
>     PATH is: /usr/bin/
>     [Pipeline] sh
>     [t_AWS-DB-resource-scheduler-TM5AGTEATY6FDJ7IENKWVPBZAIMOHYN5WXTFRS72TMHS4V4L57UA]
> Running shell script
>     ps: unrecognized option: p
>     + whoami
>     root
>     [Pipeline] sh
>     [t_AWS-DB-resource-scheduler-TM5AGTEATY6FDJ7IENKWVPBZAIMOHYN5WXTFRS72TMHS4V4L57UA]
> Running shell script
>     ps: unrecognized option: p
>     + echo /usr/bin/ansible:/usr/bin/ansible-playbook:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
>     /usr/bin/ansible:/usr/bin/ansible-playbook:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
>     [Pipeline] sh
>     [t_AWS-DB-resource-scheduler-TM5AGTEATY6FDJ7IENKWVPBZAIMOHYN5WXTFRS72TMHS4V4L57UA]
> Running shell script
>     ps: unrecognized option: p
>       -o COL1,COL2=HEADER Select columns for display
>     + /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /mnt/management/environments/localhost.ini
> /mnt/management/playbooks/utilities/aws-scheduler.yml --extra-vars
> {"mode" : "running"}
>     /var/jenkins_home/workspace/t_AWS-DB-resource-scheduler-TM5AGTEATY6FDJ7IENKWVPBZAIMOHYN5WXTFRS72TMHS4V4L57UA@tmp/durable-ae31d6ed/script.sh:
> line 1: /usr/bin/ansible-playbook: not found
```

Comment: just set the PATH to `/usr/bin/` instead of `/usr/bin/ansible`

Comment: What's the output of that pipeline?

Comment: Path already has the /usr/bin @Sudharsan Sivasankaran

Comment: @Michael It is erring out on ansible-playbook line

Comment: @KennerDev I mean the `echo`s you put in. What's the value of `$ANS_HOME` and `PATH`?

Comment: There is an ansible plugin specifically to help with this.

Comment: @Michael output for $ANS_HOME is /usr/bin/ and $PATH is <pre><code>/usr/bin/ansible:/usr/bin/ansible-playbook:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
/usr/bin/ansible:/usr/bin/ansible-playbook:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin<pre><code>

Comment: @Matt Schuchard  I got the same error when I tried using ansible plugin instead of raw shell command  ansiblePlaybook ( inventory: '/path/to/inven.ini', playbook: '/path/to/playbooks', installation: 'ansible'   ,credentialsId: 'xxxx')

Answer (score 1):

I would troubleshoot your issue following below steps:

- Check what is the folder Jenkins is using to run your playbook from, this info is in the task console.
- Make sure that Jenkins is not cleaning the repository after running the task.
- SSH into Jenkins and go to the workspace jenkins is using as the jenkins user.
- Make sure all the files are in the expected location.
- Run the script manually.
- If you can run the command manually make sure you are putting the correct command on the Pipeline, make sure there are no spaces between the paths. (I say this because the command you pasted has space between the  "/path" "/to/myinventory.ini")

Comment: I don't have a jenkins user on that box. It is run by user root

Comment: From what I see you don't need this line `PATH = "/usr/bin/ansible:/usr/bin/ansible-playbook:$PATH"`
If you don't have Jenkins user run the steps as root

Comment: One of the steps you outlined helped me to look into permissions and I discovered/learned that Jenkins is run as a container.Container do not have an ansible installed. Your answer made me ask few questions about Jenkins setup itself and learned from one of our team members that it may be a container installation that evenually led me to the solution Thanks

Comment: Jenkins user is root when Jenkins is set up using official Jenkins docker conatiner.